# Chain API call multiple parameters issue

Tags: api

We haven't been able to get executed "is_active" parameter here:
 **"api.Relationship.get": "is_active":1,"relationship_type_id":59}**
while **"relationship_type_id"** works. Here's a full query:

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "return": "display_name,id",
  "id": 150,
  "api.Relationship.get": {"is_active":1,"relationship_type_id":59}
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

For now we use this workaround (straight value check basically):

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
         "sequential": 1,
         "return": "display_name,id",
         "id": event,
         "api.Relationship.get": {"relationship_type_id": 59}
             }).done(function(result) {
                res = result.values[0]["api.Relationship.get"].values; 
                   $.each(res, function( inx, val ) {
             if (val.is_active == 1) {
            // magic
```

API Explorer doesn't complain about syntax, so shouldn't multiple parameters work "out-of-box" here or there is some kind of "hidden ingredient" to be added?